# Unable to run the session when trying to run ARKit Test

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, arkit

I'm trying to figure out how ARKit works. Therefore, I download a two different project from GitHub.

1-)https://github.com/brianadvent/Simple-ARKit-Game

2-)https://github.com/exyte/ARTetris

Both of them I'm getting " Unable to run the session, configuration is not supported on this device:  
" error. 
I'm running latest version of betas both in Xcode and iOS.

Edit: I have this code in Viewcontroller. Shouldn't It work?

```
private func getSessionConfiguration() -> ARSessionConfiguration {
    if ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration.isSupported {
        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
        return configuration;
    } else {
        // Slightly less immersive AR experience due to lower end processor
        return ARSessionConfiguration()
    }
}
```

Comment: Some Devices do not support the WorldConfiguration, which is probably set. e.g. the iPhone 6 is not supporting that. You could try to change that Configuration to default than it should work.

Comment: its support only 6s and 6s plus , 7 and 7s plus in phone

Comment: So can't I get a model on a real world scene in iPhone 6? or is it just something else?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the Variable `ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration` which is set as configuration in both Projects to a normal `ARSessionConfiguration`. Consider, that if you are doing that, you can only get the Orientation of the device and not its Position in the real World! So it could might be, that the applications are not working proberly. You could also change to another Device, which supports the `ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration` then everything should be fine, but the iPhone 6 for example cant do that.

As karthik mentioned only  6s and 6s plus , 7 and 7s plus support the WorldTracking Configuration. It is also working on iPad (5th. Gen.) AFAIK.

**Update:**
I think the Problem is, that the iPhone 6 just has a A8 processor. The ARKit Module has an *important* notice which says:

> Important
>   ARKit requires an iOS device with an A9 or later processor.
>
> To make your app available only on devices supporting ARKit, use the arkit key in the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` section of your app's `Info.plist`. If augmented reality is a secondary feature of your app, use the 
>   isSupported
>    property to determine whether the current device supports the session configuration you want to use.

If you look at the Simple-ARGame you can see, that the Touches will be listened but are computed extremely slow. I looked at an Technical Dokumentation of the [iPhone 6](http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_6-6378.php) where it says, that it only has an A8 processor. So probably you have to test ARKit with another Device.

Comment: I edited my question. I have a code which checks If It has worldtrackin or not but I'm still getting white screen. Shouldn't I get a camera instead of this?

Comment: I still don't understand the part what we can do with ARkit in iPhone 6. I mean why does it have a "ARSessionConfiguration()" function If we can't use it?

Comment: @Emre Önder, sorry but I can't answer you that Question. That is sth. which should the ARKit Team Answer you. But I think, when Apple says, everything under A9 is not supported, then ARKit was only meant for newer Devices. Probably there are some Things only A9 or later processors can do which optimizes the ARKit heavily.

Comment: Apple’s messaging was a little unclear as of WWDC / beta 1 on whether `ARSessionConfiguration` would be supported on devices earlier than A9, but even in beta 1 it didn’t actually *work* on those devices. The “Important” note from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit) @MarcelT mentions seems to clear up that it’s not intended to work on older devices.

Comment: @EmreÖnder as to “why have an API if you can’t use it?” question... when you write/compile code in Xcode you don’t know what device it might run on. You’re creating a binary that can run on any device. So Xcode can’t know whether your call to that function might succeed. You need to either check ARSessionConfiguration.isSupported before calling that API, or use UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to tell iOS to disallow installing your app on incompatible devices.

Comment: @Emre Önder, I'm not sure if your Question is still open and does not have a suitable answer, when there is sth. more you need to know please comment it and I'll try to find a answer for that, but I can't explain why the ARKit Engineers made several decisions about ARKit I can only guess what they were thinking about it. When you do not have any Questions anymore, Accept the Answer.